# Parse Html string in React

Tags: html, reactjs, html-parsing

I have big html string from backend and trying to extract some values from it:

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="teaser">
    <div class="web-text">
      <p>taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-text" style="display:none;">
      <p class="">taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text </p>
    </div>
    <img __jive_id="164943" data-image-id="164943" data-source="own" data-teaserid="164943" data-teasertext="" src="https://daimler-9040.ps.jiveint.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/102-2863-1-164943/52571303_376009123196698_8396665822503763968_o.jpg">
  </div>
  
    <div class="teaser2">
    <div class="web-text">
      <p>taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-text" style="display:none;">
      <p class="">taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text taser text </p>
    </div>
    <img __jive_id="164943" data-image-id="164943" data-source="own" data-teaserid="164943" data-teasertext="" src="https://daimler-9040.ps.jiveint.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/102-2863-1-164943/52571303_376009123196698_8396665822503763968_o.jpg">
  </div>
  
  ....
  
</div>
```

with jquery I could do that like this:

```
var text = $('.teaser .web-text').text();
```

so is there any similar solution for react to use?
I have seen 'html-react-parser' library, but that generates too many sub arrays and you have to go through all that arrays and filter them.
That's why I am searching for more easer way.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-innertext

Answer (score 0):

React is a library for Javascript, meaning that regular Javascript syntax is still available. To get the innerText for that specific DOM element you could simply use `innerText` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

Here is the specific example:
`document.getElementsByClassName('web-text')[0].firstChild.innerText`